# returned dictionary value is 'None' python

Tags: python, dictionary, return-value

I have a function in a file which I am calling in a separate script (as shown below). Printing directly from the function works correctly, however when I try to return the value to the script it sends 'None'.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

script:

```
import modules.functions as f

restype = 'THR'
atomtype = 'CA'

print f.AtomType(restype,atomtype)
```

function: (this is the part of the function which returns the value)

```
def AtomType(resName,atomType):
    def threonine():
        print 'well im here'
        atoms = {'N' : 1,
                 'CA': 6,
                 'C' : 8,
                 'O' : 2,
                 'CB': 6,
                 'OG1': 1,
                 'CG2': 4, 
                 }    

            print atoms[atomType]
            return atoms[atomType]

    residues = {'ALA' : hydrophobic,
                'ARG' : arginine,
                'ASN' : asparagine,
                'ASP' : aspartate,
                'CYS' : cysteine,
                'GLN' : glutamine,
                'GLU' : glutamate,
                'GLY' : hydrophobic,
                'HIS' : histidine,
                'ILE' : hydrophobic,
                'LEU' : hydrophobic,
                'LYS' : lysine,
                'MET' : methionine,
                'PHE' : phenylalanine,
                'PRO' : proline,
                'SER' : serine,
                'THR' : threonine,
                'TRP' : tryptophan,
                'TYR' : tyrosine,
                'VAL' : hydrophobic,
                }

    residues[resName]()
```

and the output I get is:

```
well im here
6
None
```

edit: added entire function

Comment: The first code snippet does not call the function in the second code snippet.  The function in the second snippet does not accept any parameters, but accesses some mysterious `atomType` anyway.  This is a bit confusing...  Maybe you could post the code that you are *really* trying to run?

Comment: Could you show us a complete piece of code that reproduces the fault.

Comment: You are calling `f.AtomType` and posted the code for `threonine()`. Please post the code for `f.AtomType()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a guess: `AtomType` calls `threonine`, but doesn't return its return value.